# Soundfonts play MIDI file without decay

Tags: midi, soundfont, fluidsynth, midi.js

I've been building a music notation application in Flask. On the backend I'm using Midiutil to generate midi files and [Midi.js](https://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js) on the front end to play the files.

I recorded and built my soundfont using Polyphone and converted from sf2 to JS with [soundfont_builder.rb](https://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js/blob/master/generator/ruby/soundfont_builder.rb).

The problem I am now facing is that the soundfont_builder is causing prolonged decay to the notes which I don't want.

```
def generate_midi(program, note_value, file)
  include MIDI
  seq = Sequence.new()
  track = Track.new(seq)

  seq.tracks << track
  track.events << ProgramChange.new(0, Integer(program))
  track.events << NoteOn.new(0, note_value, VELOCITY, 0) # channel, note, velocity, delta
  track.events << NoteOff.new(0, note_value, VELOCITY, DURATION)
```

Is there a way to navigate this so that my notes will play no longer or shorter than the length defined by the midi file?

I've tested my midi files with [FluidSynth](https://github.com/FluidSynth/fluidsynth) locally and they play normally as I want.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using your sf online say:

yoursoundfont.stop(youraudioontext.currentTime + 0.0);

When you stop the note say 0.0 to end instantly